# help solving this proof with remainders

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

For all $n\ge3\in \mathbb N$, if $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ then ${3^n} \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$.

I tried to set $n = 3+4k$ but it doesn't help.

Any hints first please?

Comment: I would love to help, but I don't understand the question. :(

Comment: What is "N top + sub 3"? The question is quite unclear.

Comment: Fixed it. @T.Bongers

Comment: @SonicFancy I still don't quite understand: Are you trying to show that if $n \equiv 3 \mod 4$ then $3^n \equiv 2 \mod 5$?

Comment: Yeah, I have fixed it again. Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $n = 4k + 3 \implies 3^n = 3^{(4k + 3)} = 27*81^k$. We know $27 \equiv 2 (\mod 5)$, and $81 \equiv 1 (\mod 5)$ . So $81^k \equiv 1^k = 1 (\mod 5)$. So $3^n \equiv 2*1 = 2 (\mod 5)$.

Comment: Please consider studying just a little bit of [Latex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); it doesn't require anything fancy or too much effort. It'll greatly improve the answers, and your answers won't have to be edited by other users to make the legible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect chance for induction: If $n = 3$, this is quite clear. Now suppose that the claim is true for $n = 4k + 3$. We then have

\begin{align*}
3^{4(k + 1) + 3} &= 3^{4k + 3} 3^4
\end{align*}

Now $3^4 = 3^{5 - 1}$, and Fermat's Little Theorem is applicable (or just write down $3^4$ mod $5$).

Answer (score 0):

For all $n\geq 3$, if $n = 3 \pmod 4$ then $3^n = 2 \pmod 5$.

$$3^{3+4k} = 2 \pmod 5\\
2\cdot3^{4k} = 2 \pmod 5\\
3^{4k} = 1 \pmod 5\\
\left((-2)^4\right)^{k} = 1 \pmod 5\\
1^k = 1 \pmod 5$$

Answer (score 0):

Prime $\,P\nmid A\,\Rightarrow\,A^{\large J+K(P-1)} = A^{\large J}(\color{#c00}{\large A^{P-1}})^{\large K}\equiv A^{\large J} \color{#c00}1^{\large K}\equiv A^{\large J}\!\pmod P,\ $ by $\rm\,\color{#c00}{little\ Fermat}$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply: $3^n=3^{3+4k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $3^n=27*3^{4k} \equiv 2*(3^4)^k \equiv 2*1^k \equiv2 \pmod{5}.$

We use Fermat's Little Theorem, $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for any prime number $p$.